# How to processing multiple files

Tags: spring, spring-batch

need to develop a spring batch  processing multiple flat files and save it in database
multiple flat files are section wise divided as show in the below

```
 flat file1
 // this is the format of content in the file with different sections 

 [ADDRESS]
1234 2345 N U 2   temp1 tmp1        

[name]  
 1234 Raghu Prasad
> 
> another flat file Flat2 
[State] 
1234  india hyderabad
```

where I have to retrieve "Raghu " , "Prasad" from NAME ,temp,tmp1 from ADDRESS and "hyderabad" from state where 1234 is key

need to save the data of 1234 in database

Answer (score 0):

In spring batch there is no functionality to aggregating three files.

this can be done in two ways,

1.By spring batch you can dump each file data in 3 separate tables and after that by joining all three tables data you can consolidate and persist consolidated data into a single table.

2.By spring batch first you load data from one file to database and on next file loading Spring batch "Item processor" you can compare file data and database data to load into particular row.and same repeat with the third file and so on.

Note:personally i would recommend with first process which is good in performance and time saving process.